# multi column css breaks ul content issue

Tags: html, css

I have multiple ul sections and used multi column css to split them automatically into three columns. The problem is css breaks the li content and move them to the next column. I need to move the whole ul to the next column not the individual li content.
This is the screenshot.

[image]

The result should like

[image]

This is my html code

```
<div class="columnsmulti">
<ul>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Lorem Ipsum123</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum123</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Lorem Ipsum456</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum456</li>
<li>Lorem Ipsum456</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

This is my css

```
.columnsmulti {
    -moz-column-count: 3; 
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-rule: 3px double #666;
    -webkit-column-count: 3; 
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-rule: 3px double #666;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
    column-rule: 3px double #666;
}
```

How can i do that?

Comment: ur code works fine, I don't see any li content breaking and moving to the next column.

Comment: I have checked it in mozilla firefox. Please refer the screenshot in my edited question.

Comment: inspect in firebug, what is there in the empty spaces ? I am not facing that issue in any browser. Here is the fiddle - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/uHzSQ/1/)

Comment: I think you have mistaken the bug. The content Lorem ipsum belongs to the first ul and the content lorem ipsum 123 belongs to the second ul. I need to break the column with whole ul not li. Please refer the screen shot for required result.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this without using multi column css?

Comment: right sorry. `column-count` property doesn't need 3 ul's for 3 columns.  if you give just one ul and do `column-count=3` then you will get 3 columns. If I wanted to do something like this then I would have used `float` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the column-break rules in css. Here's an example applies for Chrome:

```
.columnsmulti ul {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -webkit-column-break-after: always;
}
```

Add these lines in your css and it'll work as your demand.

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#break-before-break-after-break-inside)

P.S.: Seems `-moz-column-break` isn't recognized by my Firefox.